# Why override object.GetHashCode() and object.Equals(object) when implementing Comparer<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I was browsing a codebase, and I notice that the definition of a subclass of [`Comparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.comparer-1?view=net-5.0) overrides [`object.GetHashCode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=net-6.0) and [`object.Equals(object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-6.0). For example:

```cs
public class MyComparer : Comparer<MyClass> {
  public override int Compare(MyClass x, MyClass y) {
    return x == y ? 0 : x == null ? -1 : Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(x.Value, y.Value);
  }

  public override bool Equals(object obj) {
    return obj is MyComparer;
  }

  public override int GetHashCode() {
    return typeof(MyClass).Name.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

I noticed that this seemed to be copying the pattern from [the .net reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/comparer.cs,4bdedf7e4e4851ba), [Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/5d2e3bc3b3c8184d35b2f7801e88d96470d367c4/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/comparer.cs#L122), and even [.net-core](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3ae87395f638a533f37b8e3385f6d3f199a72f4f/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Comparer.cs#L50).

Is there any point to this? It seems even more pointless for the framework-provided classes which are only reachable via static properties and are thus singleton—the default implementation of `object.Equals(object)` and `object.GetHashCode()` works fine on singletons because reference identity is sufficient.

I noticed also that the implementations are decorated with `SerializableAttribute`. Could this be related? Is the idea that multiple instances could be created by serialization and then someone who is using a comparer as a dictionary key (why?) would be relying on that behavior?

But even though `ComparisonComparer<T>` is decorated with `SerializableAttribute`, it doesn’t override `object.GethashCode()` or `object.Equals(object)`. Is this because it was introduced to the framework more recently and the framework authors realized that overriding the two methods in question was pointless and could omit it because the type was new but could not remove it from the other types due to compatibility concerns?

Anyway, what is the best practice and why? Can/should I write code which assumes these methods are implemented for every implementation of `Comparer<T>`?

Comment: Keep in mind that this is only useful if the client programmer stores MyComparer objects in a collection.  The burden of a framework developer is that they can never predict how their objects are going to be used.  When you make your own comparer, you don't have the same worry and can easily omit these overrides.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your response! I agree. However, the framework doesn't override these for `Comparison compared<T>` even though delegate equality is well-defined. Do you have any insights on why that might be?

Comment: It is a delegate, overriding Equals/GetHashCode is not possible.  And it is well-defined.

Comment: @HansPassant [`ComparisonComparer<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3ae87395f638a533f37b8e3385f6d3f199a72f4f/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Comparer.cs#L33) has a delegate member. But why doesn’t it implement `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(object)` and delegate those calls to the delegate?

Comment: It is `internal`, no danger of anybody storing it in a collection.

Comment: @HansPassant It is returned by [`Comparer<T>.Create(Comparison<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.comparer-1.create?view=net-5.0) ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3ae87395f638a533f37b8e3385f6d3f199a72f4f/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Comparer.cs#L16)).